# Cherry pick an australian address from a page of text

Tags: php, regex, street-address, cherry-pick

I am trying to parse a prose paragraph for anything that might resemble an address. I have a database of addresses I am matching against and these are the only addresses I am interested in. I'm using a lamp server but technology specific answers aren't what I require right now. More of a question of how.

Can anyone provide ideas? Perhaps Regex? or perhaps I should use a database of cities/states etc?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm going to rephrase this question. Right now I'm using my phone relaxing on a beach. Need a laptop to write it out clearly.

Comment: ...so, what's your actual question? Reads more like a brain-dump on ideas.

Comment: okay made it more direct

Comment: address-parser.com is a possible solution, does anyone know the price?

Comment: For those of us in a different hemisphere (on one or more axes), could you provide some sample addresses, please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question hasn't gotten answered because it's entirely unclear what the problem parameters are. If you want a more specific answer to a problem, please describe your problem more fully.

In general I would suggest aproaching a problem like this using some piece of known data ... small collection of words or formats that delieniate and address, then match on the context of those words to see if they really flesh out to a full address.